# Oracle SQL Query to Distribute a value into different rows based on priority

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to write SQL query which distribute or adds a value into different rows based on priority.

Here is my scenario.

I have table called `M_FLIGHT` with below data.

```
DEPARTURE_DATE  FLIGHT_NO  FAIR_TYPE          PRIORITY  AVAILABLE_SEATS  MAX_CAPACITY  RETURN_SEAT
==============  =========  =================  ========  ===============  ============  ===========
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Normal Fair           1         7                10             4
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Maharaja Standard     2         8                10             0
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Maharaja Special      3         9                10             0
```

A flight can have different fair types( i.e Normal Fair, Maharaja Standard, Maharaja Delhi Special so on) with priorities 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

If user cancels/returns the booked seats then I need to add `RETURN_SEAT` value to the `AVAILABLE_SEATS` value such that it should not exceed the `MAX_CAPACITY` value for that fair type.

If it exceeds then add remaining value to next priority(i.e to next fair type).

So, the final result should be as below

```
DEPARTURE_DATE  FLIGHT_NO  FAIR_TYPE          PRIORITY  AVAILABLE_SEATS  MAX_CAPACITY  RETURN_SEAT
==============  =========  =================  ========  ===============  ============  ===========
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Normal Fair           1         10               10             4
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Maharaja Standard     2         9                10             0
05-DEC-14       SC-917     Maharaja Special      3         9                10             0
```

Comment: Is that for educational or production purposes? The above final result is for returning four Priority 1 seats, isn't it?

Comment: This is for production purpose.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

RETURN_SEAT column value will remain same(No Changes) and only AVAILABLE_SEATS column values should be changed.

For PRIORITY = 1, the RETURN_SEAT value is 4. 
So we need to add this value(4) to AVAILABLE_SEATS value(7) of PRIORITY 1, But it should not exceed the MAX_CAPACITY value(i.e 10)
If it exceed then add the remaining value to next PRIORITY(i.e 2).

Comment: Example:
For PRIORITY = 1, Maximum you can add 3 to AVAILABLE_SEATS(7) out of 4, So remaining is 1.
For PRIORITY = 2, Since remaining value is 1. we have to add this remaining value(1) to AVAILABLE_SEATS(8), So remaining is 0.
For PRIORITY = 3, Since remaining value is 0. No need to add since it remains the same.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate the occupied space using a cumulative sum:

```
select f.*, sum(max_capacity-available_seats) as occupied,
        sum(max_capacity-available_seats) over (order by priority) as cumeocc
from m_flight f;
```

With this information, you can allocate `v_Num` new seats:

```
select f.*,
       (case when v_Num >= cumeocc - occupied
             then greatest(v_num - (cumeocc - occupied), occupied)
             else occupied
        end) as new_occupied
from (select f.*, (max_capacity-available_seats) as occupied,
              sum(max_capacity-available_seats) over (order by priority) as cumeocc
      from m_flight f
     ) f;
```

Then the next step is to merge this information back.  That is a bit hard to express, because you don't have an obvious key on each row.  I would suggest you add a single-column primary key to the table.

Comment: Thank you very much for your assistance.

When I executed this query I got below errors.

1. "ORA-00937: not a single-group group function" for inner sub query.
    I rectified this by adding Group By Function.
 
2. ORA-00904: "V_NUM": invalid identifier.
   I am not able resolve this.

V_NUM refers to which column?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a update query for this business.

```
update M_FLIGHT d
   set d.AVAILABLE_SEATS =
       (select case
                 when (f.available_seats + Case
                        when ((select sum(s.return_seat) from M_FLIGHT s) -
                             nvl((select sum(s.max_capacity - s.available_seats)
                                    from M_FLIGHT s
                                   where s.priority < f.priority),
                                  0)) > 0 THEN
                         ((select sum(s.return_seat) from M_FLIGHT s) -
                         nvl((select sum(s.max_capacity - s.available_seats)
                                from M_FLIGHT s
                               where s.priority < f.priority),
                              0))
                        Else
                         0
                      END) >= f.max_capacity then
                  f.max_capacity
                 else
                  (f.available_seats + Case
                    when ((select sum(s.return_seat) from M_FLIGHT s) -
                         nvl((select sum(s.max_capacity - s.available_seats)
                                from M_FLIGHT s
                               where s.priority < f.priority),
                              0)) > 0 THEN
                     ((select sum(s.return_seat) from M_FLIGHT s) -
                     nvl((select sum(s.max_capacity - s.available_seats)
                            from M_FLIGHT s
                           where s.priority < f.priority),
                          0))
                    Else
                     0
                  END)
               end as avail_new
          from M_FLIGHT f
         where f.priority = d.priority);
```

I know that's to hard to read this query, but it works. Maybe you need to add some filters for sub queries (like DEPARTURE_DATE,FLIGHT_NO,...).

Thank you for Bring up some issue that needs to think a lot. I liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26957178/15682171) answer

I think this query could help you

```
select f.*,
       (case
         when 4 >= free_seat_sumover - free_seat then
          least(4 - (free_seat_sumover - free_seat), free_seat)
       
         else
          0
       end) as new_occupied
  from (select f.*,
               (max_capacity - available_seats) as free_seat,
               sum(max_capacity - available_seats) over(order by priority) as free_seat_sumover
          from m_flight f) f;
```

which 4 is the RETURN_SEAT column value